# What's the difference between Chtml::encode and CHtmlPurifier?

Tags: yii, encode

To show content from a database, should I use `Chtml::encode()` or `CHtmlPurifier()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on whether it is HTML content or not. If not, use `CHtml::encode()` for the data, as there shouldn't be HTML entities in it.

If you need to display HTML content, use CHtmlPurifier